# Superscript in enumerate/paralist labels

Tags: enumerate, labels, paralist

When setting a label type like `\begin{inparaenum}[a)]` in paralist it will treat `a`,`1`,`i` as a special character and increment it accordingly **as long as it isn't in a `{}` group**. I want the labels to be superscript upright a,b,c like:

<sup>a</sup> first thing
<sup>b</sup> second thing
<sup>c</sup> and another thing

I can't use enumitem (I know it can do this). If you try it in `enumerate` or `paralist` packages (or `enumitems` with `oldenum`) you have the problem that `\textsuperscript` etc. put the `a` in braces and so it isn't incremented, and using mathmode like `$^a$` works (in italic), but then trying to use `\text` or `\mathrm` has the same problem.

How can I make `paralist` use superscript upright labels?

Here are two failed attempts, and one example that works, but using the forbidden `enumitems`.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\medskip{}

\begin{inparaenum}[a)]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{inparaenum}
\medskip{}

\begin{inparaenum}[$^a$]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{inparaenum}
\medskip{}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\textsuperscript{\alph*}]
\item one 
\item two 
\item three 
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: example output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{inparaenum}[\expandafter\textsuperscript a ]
\item First item,
\item Second item.
\end{inparaenum}
\bigskip

\begin{asparaenum}[\expandafter\textsuperscript a ]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{asparaenum}

\begin{enumerate}[\expandafter\textsuperscript a ]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I don't know how I'd ever find an answer like this without reading the whole TeX books, or asking here.

Comment: I didn't read the whole TeX books, but I happen to have met problems solved with `\expandafter`, so I tried, just in case… and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If there no such thing in `paralist`, why don't you define your's?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}

\makeatletter
\def\inparaenumsup{%
  \ifnum\@enumdepth>\thr@@
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
  \fi
  \@ifnextchar[{\@enumlabel@{\@inparaenum@sup}[}{\@inparaenum@sup}}
\def\@inparaenum@sup{%
  \usecounter{\@enumctr}%
  \def\@itemlabel{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}%
  \let\@item\pl@item
  \def\makelabel##1{\textsuperscript{##1}}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

The superscript version (bare):

\begin{inparaenumsup}[a]
\item first thing 
\item second thing 
\item and another thing
\end{inparaenumsup}


The superscript version (with parenthesis):

\begin{inparaenumsup}[(a)]
\item first thing 
\item second thing 
\item and another thing
\end{inparaenumsup}


And the original version is untouched:
\begin{inparaenum}[a]
\item first thing 
\item second thing 
\item and another thing
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

**How It Works?**

We are creating a new type of list called `inparaenumsup` by hacking
into the internals of `paralist`.

Actully, we touch the definition of 
`\makelabel` and change it from 
  `\def\makelabel##1{##1}` to 
`\def\makelabel##1{\textsuperscript{##1}}`